# Randomly increasing sequence- Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: sequence, wolfram-mathematica, recurrence

Good afternoon, I have a problem making recurrence table with randomly increasing sequence. I want it to return an increasing sequence with a random difference between two elements. Right now I've got:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[k+1]==a[k] + RandomInteger[{0,4}], a[1]==-12},a,{k,1,5}]
```

But it returns me an arithmetic progression with chosen d for all *k* (e.g. {-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,16,20,24}).

Also, I will be really grateful for explaining why if I replace every *k* in my code with *n* I get:

```
RecurrenceTable[{4+a[n] == a[n],a[1] == -12},a,{n,1,10}]
```

Thank You very much for Your time!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that `RecurrenceTable` is what you are looking for.

Try this instead

```
FoldList[Plus,-12,RandomInteger[{0,4},5]]
```

which returns, this time,

```
{-12,-8,-7,-3,1,2}
```

and returns, this time,

```
{-12,-9,-5,-3,0,1}
```